# Presto how to find start date given week

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I want to find start date from given **ISO week** (which can range from **1-53**, **Monday** as starting day) and year using Presto SQL query.

i.e. year - 2020 and week - 2 should return 06/01/2020

Is there any inbuilt function for this ?

**Table structure:**

```
select year, week from table1; // returns year and week from table table 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no direct way for constructing a date from a year + week (there is an issue for this: https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/2287), but you can achieve what you want with the [`date_parse`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse) function.

For example:

```
WITH data (year, week) AS (VALUES (2020, 2))
SELECT CAST(date_parse(CAST(year AS varchar) || ':' || CAST(week AS varchar), '%x:%v') AS date)
FROM data
```

produces:

```
   _col0
------------
 2020-01-06
(1 row)
```

Comment: This will have a bug for the first week of the year where the start of the week is the previous year. The answer below is correct one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65571134/8203233 

Perhaps edit this to ensure others don't use it incorrectly?

Comment: Can you provide an example where the result is incorrect? The %x format specifier represents "Year for the week, where Monday is the first day of the week" (see https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?#mysql-date-functions)

Comment: My bad, the question here is asking for with given week and year to return the start date. 

The example I was thinking was this 

```WITH data (ds) AS (VALUES ('2023-01-01'))
SELECT CAST(date_parse(CAST(YEAR(DATE(ds)) AS varchar) || ':' || CAST(WEEK(DATE(ds)) AS varchar), '%x:%v') AS date) AS week_num
FROM data```. This will incorrectly return `2023-12-25`. But it's a different question from what's asked in this STO

Answer (score 1):

Using **DATE_ADD** and **MAKEDATE** you can achieve the result...

```
select DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(year, 1), INTERVAL (week-1) WEEK) as start_date from <table_name>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Martin's answer is almost there. Instead of using `year`, you should use `year_of_week`. Though with this change you'll have to make sure to not have a bug with weeks that bleed into the following or previous year i.e. last days of the previous year or first days of the next year.

`year_of_week` returns the year of the ISO week.

Here's an example:

```
WITH data (year, week) AS (VALUES (2020, 2))
SELECT CAST(date_parse(CAST(year_of_week AS varchar) || ':' || CAST(week AS varchar), '%x:%v') AS date)
FROM data
```

---

**References:**

- https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#year_of_week
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Answer (score 0):

I think for partial weeks (when first days in a new year is still counted as week 53) this does not work:

> Query failed (#20210624_142222_02859_zf75v): Cannot parse "2021:53": Value 53 for weekOfWeekyear must be in the range [1,52]

tested by this formula:

The date was on Jan  2,2021 which is still treated as week53 but in 2021...

```
CAST(date_parse(CAST(year(date(service_order_creation_date)) AS varchar) || ':' || CAST(week(date(service_order_creation_date)) AS varchar), '%x:%v') AS date)
```

[image]

Comment: I met this issue too. Have you found out any solution?

Comment: same here any solution on this ?